# Transferring data from one workbook to another workbook daily into specific/empty cells

Tags: vba, excel, rowcount, is-empty

I am in the process of developing a macro that will Transfer Data from one workbook `(enterdata)` to another workbook `(extractdata)` while having a mass collection of formulas in the `extractdata` workbook. I need to have the data extracted into specific cells as data gets input day by day. This data needs to be compiled and I am having troubles with this portion.

I need the data extracted into specific cells because if I use the empty row functions I have formulas at the end of my rows and bottom of my columns therefore I am trying to have the data input into specific cells

I think I am on the right track but I continuously have `Run-time error '1004':` stating `select method of range class failed`.

Thanks in advance,
Anderson

```
'Next the transfers of the data from the daily quality activity to the specific worksheet of the unit charts'
'Accesories'
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\database\Extractdata.xlsm")
Worksheets("ACC").Select

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1   'column A has a value of 1
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    For currentRow = 3 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
        End If
    Next

With Worksheets("ACC").Range("A3")
.Offset(ColumnCount, 0) = currentDate
.Offset(ColumnCount, 1) = devicesStockedACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 2) = qipAttemptsACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 3) = qipncproductCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 4) = totalqcncCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 5) = devicencidCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 6) = componentncidCountACC
End With



NEW CODE 3/13/14


Dim currentDate As String

Dim devicesStockedACC As String
Dim qipAttemptsACC As String
Dim qipncproductCountACC As String
Dim totalqcncCountACC As String
Dim devicencidCountACC As String
Dim componentncidCountACC As String

'Acessories'
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
currentDateACC = Range("A1")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
devicesStockedACC = Range("C12")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
qipAttemptsACC = Range("D12")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
qipncproductCountACC = Range("E12")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
totalqcncCountACC = Range("H12")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
devicencidCountACC = Range("L12")
Worksheets("tuesday").Select
componentncidCountACC = Range("M12")


'Next the transfers of the data from the daily quality activity to the specific worksheet of the unit charts'
'Accesories'
Set myData = Workbooks.Open("C:\database\Extractdata.xlsm")
Worksheets("ACC").Select
Worksheets("ACC").Range("A3").Select

Application.Run "Selectfirstblankcell"



Sheets("ACC").Activate

With Worksheets("ACC").Range(ActiveCell)
.Offset(ColumnCount, 0) = currentDate
.Offset(ColumnCount, 1) = devicesStockedACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 2) = qipAttemptsACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 3) = qipncproductCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 4) = totalqcncCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 5) = devicencidCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 6) = componentncidCountACC
.Offset(ColumnCount, 8) = currentDate
.Offset(ColumnCount, 15) = currentDate
End With



Application.Run "Selectfirstblankcell" = 

Public Sub SelectFirstBlankCell()
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1   'column F has a value of 6
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
    For currentRow = 3 To rowCount
    For currentCol = 1 To ColCount
        currentCellValue = Cells(currentRow, currentCol).FormulaR1C1
        If IsEmpty(currentCellValue) Or currentCellValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Select 'do something else than select maybe?
            'put code here to handle the empty cell
            Exit For 'this will exit the inner loop, so it will only process the first blank cell on each row
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont get any errors when I run that code. Where are you getting the error? None of the variables in the `with` block at the end are included anywhere in the posted code. Also you can't use `.select` to select more than one row at a time... so each time you select a new cell the previous one is deselected. use the debugger to step through your code and watch whats happening

Comment: Okay I appreciate the help. I have got it to run now, It there anyway for it to start at currentRow(3) and go to the first empty cell? Currently it will loop until there is a filled cell below it. Do you know How I could get it to run to the first blank cell regardless if there is a empty cell or filled cell below it. 

I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

try using `.formulaR1C1` instead of `.value`. your current code should run to the first empty cell in `sourceCol`

```
For currentRow = 3 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).formulaR1C1
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then 
        Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
    End If
Next
```

your above code (I changed from `.value` to `.formular1C1`) will loop through each row in sourceCol, and that if statement will be true if the current cell is empty. to loop through each cell (column) on each row you'd need another for loop. 1 for going down, 1 for going accross

```
For currentRow = 3 To rowCount
    for currentCol = 1 to ColCount
        currentCellValue = Cells(currentRow, currentCol).formulaR1C1
        If IsEmpty(currentCellValue) Or currentCellValue = "" Then 
            Cells(currentRow, currentCol).Select 'do something else than select maybe?
            'put code here to handle the empty cell
            exit for 'this will exit the inner loop, so it will only process the first blank cell on each row
        End If
    next
Next
```

so that code will loop through each row, and the inner loop will loop over the columns in that row, and the if statement in the inner loop will be true when it encounters a blank cell, you can put whatever code in the if, and then it will exit the inner for loop, so as to only process the first blank column in each row. it wont exit the outer loop though, it'll move on to the next row.

Let me know how that works for you

### edit

after the line: `rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row`

add this: `colCount = Cells.find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).column`

when you use the debugger you can see the values of all your local variables. so when stuff like that happens where it just does nothing, make sure you check those get initialized.

sorry about not including that. now the inner loop should run.

also, in accessories, this: `Worksheets("tuesday").Select` only needs to be inlcluded once at the top of the accessories section. doing this: `DevicesStockedAcc = Range("A1")` doesnt deselect the worksheet so you dont need to select it again every time.

Also, I noticed when setting the accessories you're doing: `currentDateACC = Range("A1")` i also notcied the variable: `currentDateACC` you have as a string. so is this variable supposed to represent the value of a cell? or the cell itself? using just `.range` will get you a reference to the range, not the value in the cell. to get the value use: `devicesStockedACC = Range("C12").value` that will save the value in that cell as the string, and similarly, when doing your offsets use: `.Offset(ColumnCount, 1).value = devicesStockedACC` that should help some :)

Comment: So I had the Worksheet start at the Range "A2", which wasnt empty then ran the application that you provided. I did'nt seem to move at when stepping the whole code. And Now I am having trouble with setting the values in the cells with the offset command I am using. I am new to VBA and my apologize for the hassel, I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: I have added what my code is now with your help in the above dialog box.

Comment: haha I didnt set the colCount in my code so it would be 0. I editted my answer